# Amazon ec2 price calculations per visit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

Im trying to build a financial model to run some projections for a web project.  I am wanting to use Amazon ec2 but I dont know how to figure out the cost for traffic levels (i.e. visitors, length of visit etc) with instance rates.

Can someone help me with the calculations.

For example, if I have 1000 visits to the site for 3 minutes each, how many instances will that use. what about 10000, 100000 and so on?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: With the information you've given it would be impossible to predict. If your site serves a single, static HTML file through NGINX cost per visit would be very low, if every request requires 5 seconds of processing it would be very high. To get an accurate calculation you'll need to run some CPU benchmarks on the complete application, on an EC2 instance, but even then it will be very difficult and most likely inaccurate. Large web services companies can spend years trying to get these calculations right.

Comment: The site will play videos that have been submited.  The videos are hosted and delivered by another service.  The part hosted on Amazon will just be the basic shell (i.e. layout design and basic navigation functionality, links and facebook commenting api)

Comment: even so, without fully benchmarking the application you won't be able to get any price estimates. Just for example, you can write an identical application in PHP and Python Tornado, Python Tornado will almost always be cheaper than PHP, even though there doing the same thing

Answer (score 1):

EC2 instances are priced based on the number of hours the instance is ON, regardless of CPU. Think of it like buying a dedicated machine for X hours, not like buying CPU cycles.

The variance in the cost is bandwidth consumed, so you would have to figure out how much bandwidth the 1000 users will consume for those 3 minutes.

Amazon has a calculator to help you figure out your costs http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html